# why is .sort return 0 reordering my results?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It took me forever to track down this bug. I'm running a sort on things with the same sort values, so my sort compare function always returns 0. Shouldn't this keep their order the same!? Usually it does, but here it's not. How can I keep the order the same?

[image]

Comment: it depends on the sort algorithm... actually, you are treating all values as same so any order should be fine ;)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), what happens when `0` is returned from your sorting function isn't guaranteed by the spec. Additionally, sorting in JS isn't guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: And I know it might seem like dfsq is being pedantic, but it's generally preferred for code to be included in the body of your question, rather than in an image. I'm not 100% sure of the reasoning behind this, but I assume it's so if someone searches for a particular piece of code, they'll find your question (and the answers).

Comment: I couldn't get any reproducible code /: Every simple example didn't have this issue. Only these complex result objects do. Having my code won't help you much. So what do I do? Find some random sort function someone else made? What's it called if a sort function keeps items of same value in their place?